# CSS: Make footer always at bottom of page even on scroll

Tags: css, html, footer

So I've come across this issue with my footer. Basically, I managed to make it so that the footer always appears at the bottom of the web page...when the content of the site doesn't reach it. However, when the content reaches the footer you obviously need to scroll down. But, when scrolling the footer stays were it is. This is with a position of absolute.

So, I changed the position to fixed to have a look at it that way. The footer so always stay at the bottom of the page but when you it stays there even on scroll.

What I need is for the footer to ALWAYS be at the bottom of the content UNLESS the content is not enough to fill the user's screen in which case the footer moves to the bottom of the screen. My CSS for the footer is below. Any ideas?

```
footer{
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #F1F0EE;
    color: #999;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you need to use JavaScript to do this

Comment: To be honest, I did already think of this but before I went ahead with anything I wanted to make sure there was nothing you could do with css. Shame you can't really. Thanks for the response. I think I'll just keep it as fixed because it's not a bad result and there'll only be a couple of pages with masses of content. Thanks anyhow

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the height of your content you can achieve this using a simple two div layout - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZj9D/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="content">Content</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#content {
    height:100%;
    min-height:300px; /* This is the height of your content + height of the footer */
}
#footer {
    margin-top:-100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#f00;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you could use a three line table as a layout and put your footer content in the third line. Hope it helps

Comment: Nah, that's no god. I'll never structure a website through tables. Thanks anyway though :)

Comment: @davidb : Why is everybody on stackOverflow is against table formatting?

Comment: @FranckNgako literal `<table>` should only be used for actual tabular data, though. `display: table` is however completely valid and extensively used especially if you want to create fluid designs.

Comment: @FranckNgako I think tables are fine when there is an actual table on the web page. If you are not creating a table then CSS is your friend.

Comment: @FranckNgako tables were successfully used in early web development era, with the advancement of div layout and responsiveness, tables (for HTML layouts) are becoming obsolete. In fact, you can bootstrap a grid better than a table would. It will not surprise me if tables end up becoming deprecated and suffering the same demise of the old Frames layouts. and P.S. it's not everyone in SO is against tables, it's every Front End Developer for that matter ;) lol